# animateColorAsState depending of a progress from 0 to 1

Tags: animation, android-jetpack-compose, pager

I have a Pager from which I get the position progress from `0` to `1`. I would like to change the background color of the Surface that contains the Pager depending on the `PagerState` the same way I was able to do it for alphas:

```
val alphaAnimation by animateFloatAsState(
    targetValue = progress, // <- derivedStateOf PagerState
    animationSpec = spring(stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMedium),
    label = ""
)
```

Is it possible to use the same progress between 2 color values?

I didn't find a way using for `animateColorAsState`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to use a float value between 0f and 1f for changing between 2 colors you can use linear interpolation function for Color which is

```
fun lerp(start: Color, stop: Color, @FloatRange(from = 0.0, to = 1.0) fraction: Float): Color
```

For instance as `lerp(Color.Red, Color.Green, progress)` can be used to change color based on pager swipe if you change the range from 0f to 1f.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly: `val colorAnimation by animateColorAsState(
    targetValue = lerp(currentPage.background, targetPage.background, progress),
    label = "animate color"
)`